# How to fix key-error : 'x-wp-totalpages' when using woocommerce api in django

Tags: django, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I can not fetch total_pages in order to proceed with data afterwards
The problem is in line:

```
total_pages = int(r.headers['X-WP-TotalPages'])
```

The traceback from command line is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/vhosts/example.gr/rodkok_inventory/intranet/views.py", line 731, in update_orders
    get_from_woocommerce_orders(eshop)
  File "/var/www/vhosts/example.gr/rodkok_inventory/intranet/views.py", line 237, in get_from_woocommerce_orders
    total_pages = int(r.headers['X-WP-TotalPages'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'x-wp-totalpages'
```

My view function is:

```
def get_from_woocommerce_orders(eshop):
    wcapi = API(
        url=eshop.url,
        consumer_key=eshop.consumer_key,
        consumer_secret=eshop.consumer_secret,
        wp_api=True,
        version="wc/v2",
        query_string_auth=True,
        verify_ssl = True,
        timeout=10
    )
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(2)
    r=wcapi.get("orders?after="+str(yesterday)+"T00:00:00Z")
    total_pages = int(r.headers['X-WP-TotalPages'])
```

Can anyone have an idea why I came up with error **KeyError: 'x-wp-totalpages'?**

Comment: what is in r.headers?

Comment: @HenryM the total number of pages encompassing all available records. I just realize that the request gives Response 500, so it maybe is a server error